# Когда есть смысл в постоянном соединении с MySQL в PDO?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql, pdo

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php
Пример #4 Постоянные соединения

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

Позвольте процитирую:

> Постоянные соединения не закрываются при завершении работы скрипта,
>   они кэшируются и используются повторно, когда другой скрипт
>   запрашивает соединение с теми же учетными данными. Постоянные
>   соединения позволяют избежать создания новых подключений каждый раз,
>   когда требуется обмен данными с базой, что в результате дает прирост
>   скорости работы таких приложений.

Но я так понял в случае возникновения проблем (скрипт заблокировал таблицу) все ждут, соединение-то одно. Открытые транзакции будут продолжены при нештатном завершении работы (непонятно что они будут делать данных-то в скрипте уже нет для продолжения транзакции).

Вопросы:

1) правильно ли я понял что постоянные соединения имеет смысл использовать только в демонах например, которые постоянно работают с одной базой и запущены в единственном экземпляре, т.е. не конкурируют между собой?

2) В PostgreSQL не раз слышал что вроде бы успешно применяется пул соединений (коннектов) но как они обходят ту же самую проблему с транзакциями?

3) Вообще для каких сайтов, веб-проектов есть смысл в постоянных соединениях?

Comment: Ну для демона то точно не нужно. Он же не завершается и сам держит свое соединение. А теперь представьте обычный web, не особенно нагруженный логикой, который в основном читает БД и изредка пишет в отдельные таблицы, причем на сессии стоит автокоммит (он по умолчанию) и приложение не пользуется begin transaction потому как ему не надо менять несколько связанных таблиц друг за другом. И таких приложений на вебе процентов 90 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вообще для каких сайтов, веб-проектов есть смысл в постоянных соединениях?

Для тех, которым критичны те миллисекунды, которые уходят на соединение с базой данных.

> но как они обходят ту же самую проблему с транзакциями?

В нормальных реализациях постоянного соединения производится сброс состояния. К примеру, не знаю как Постгрес, но mysqli при каждом новом соединении вызывает функцию change_user(), которая и очищает соединение... что, в свою очередь, обратно увеличивает время соединения, делая постоянное соединение менее оправданным. PDO, насколько я знаю, соединение не очищает.

про демоны написали выше в комментарии - они тут не приделах совсем.

В качестве резюме можно написать - с постоянными соединениями лучше не связываться, особенно в PDO.

Comment: То есть нет ни каких противопоказаний к написанию своего расширенного класса PDOStatement для использование его со своим классом на основе PDO?

Comment: Ну, учитывая, что единственным известным мне  противопоказанием является как раз невозможность создать постоянное соединение - то да